# How can I make a set of numbers that increase every 30 seconds to line up in an ascending order?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, sorting, auto-increment

If you run this javascript code below,

```
var i = 20220215155;
    function increment(){
     i++;
        document.getElementById('period').innerHTML += i + "<br />" + "<hr />" ;
    }   
    setInterval('increment()', 32100);
```

you will see that after every 30 seconds, the numbers (20220215155) gets incremented and each increment is printed on a new line. E.g;

**20220215156

20220215157

20220215158

20220215159

20220215160**

But I want each print to sort this way after each incrementation;

**20220215160

20220215159

20220215158

20220215157

20220215156**

Whereby if **20220215156** is on the first line, after 30 seconds, **20220215157** should be on the first line and the previous numbers goes to the second line automatically and after the next 30 seconds, **20220215158** appears in the first line and so on. I just hope anyone understands.

*Please I need help doing that.*

Comment: Realitively speaking, if numbers are sorted numerically, adding 1 to each one, even repeatidly shouldn't change the sort order.

Comment: Do you want to reduce by one each time or to add each entry to the top of the list?

Comment: Each entry to the top list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let info = document.getElementById('info');
let num = 20220215155;

setInterval(() => {
    let newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.innerHTML = `${++num}<hr>`;
    info.insertBefore(newElement, info.childNodes[0]); //Adding newElement at the beginning of the parent
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="info">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working perfectly but how do I separate them with a horizontal rule?

Comment: You can use innerHTML for this task. I have added the required changes to the code.

Answer (score 2):

[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is useful here. You can use the `afterbegin` property to add new elements containing the numbers to the top of the container.

```js
const i = 20220215155;
const div = document.querySelector('#period');

// The function accepts a variable (the new number)
function increment(i) {

  // Prepend the number to the container
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div>${i}</div><hr>`);

  // Call the function again with an incremented number
  setTimeout(increment, 1000, ++i);

}

increment(i);
```

```html
<div id="period"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Working awesomely but how do I separate them with a horizontal rule?

Comment: Answer updated @Wiggins. Just add in the `hr` element to the template string.